# OutOfMemoryError while deploying a war from Jenkins to Tomcat

Tags: java, shell, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

I deploy my application from Jenkins my using the following shell command:

```
rm -rf E:/FooTomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/foo-web;
rm -rf E:/FooTomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/foo-web.war;
sleep 2;
cp foo-web/target/foo-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war E:/FooTomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/foo-web.war
```

Often when the periodic build is started the Tomcat runs out of memory giving the following error.

```
Feb 13, 2015 3:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive E:\FooTomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\foo-web.war
Feb 13, 2015 4:00:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:818)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1658)
```

I have a windows environment and executing the shell through cygwin.

Is someting wrong with the shell command, or is it due to some memory leak? I introduced the sleep to give some time for the application to undeploy. I have never tried by increasing the sleep duration.

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance to run your Tomcat under Java 8? In Java 8, the _Permanent Generation_ (PermGen) space was replaced by an expandable _Metaspace_.

Comment: Why don't you use the tomcat manager webapp instead? Also, it looks like you are running this script on a "live" server, am I right?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  No, its not possible to run the tomcat with Java 8.

Comment: @fge Yes, the tomcat service is running while the script runs, does it effects the deployment?. I'm not exactly sure what is "tomcat manager webapp", I will google it.

Comment: Well, chances are it may affect it, yes, especially since you run Windows

Comment: @fge I have set my Tomcat as a windows service, and I am unable to find a way to stop it from the shell, Do you happen to know, how it can be achived?

Comment: I didn't say that you had to stop it. I suggested that you configured the manager webapp, which allows you to undeploy/redeploy apps at runtime, including from wars. That is, imho, a much better option than just removing the directory and creating it anew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception indicates your problem comes from filling up the PermGen space. It is a part of memory where Java stores the metadata about your classes (let's say the code of your loaded classes). When you deploy a new web-app you add new classes and increase the load of PermGen. What is worse, when you re-deploy the same app in 90% of the cases, the previous versions of the used classes stays in the memmory so you do not release the 'old' memory from PermGen but just add to it (the 90% estimation comes from using DataBase drivers, frameworks which uses ThreadLocal, Scheduler threads ... in reality it happens almost all the time).

The default permgen is too small (like 64M or something as ridiculous). Start tomcat with higher values, you do it by passing to tomcat the JVM options, for example:

JAVA_OPTS = -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx4024m

(first set the perm size to 512MB second the heap size to 4G, which is fine for modern system).

You set this variable before you start tomcat, or (I prefer it that way, you can modify your /bin/catalina script to always have them set up there, that way you will not 'forget' them if you start your tomcat again).

From tomact 7, when you undeploy app, the tomcat logs show warnings of apps that stays in memmory (and fill up your PermGen), you may want to check them and try to fix some problems (updating frameworks, shuting down properly your threads pool ...)

Comment: I have tried increasing the space, this is my current configuration: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m. It looks sufficient to me.

Comment: But has it solved your problem? 2G for max perm size is probably over kill especially that your heap is only 1G now.

Comment: I had used a enw configuration yesterday, "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m", and again in the nightly build I had the same error. I have a query though do I need to set the parameters in "catalina.sh" or "catalina.bat" ?

Comment: On windows bat, on linux sh. If the tomcat starts as service on windows I am not sure (I guess also in catalina.sh but you should chek it). And of course you need to restart the server.

Comment: If you go to tomcat welcome page, manager, server status, you will set the current memory consumptions and max settings. Check if they match your configurations. If they do and you still get Exception there is something wrong with your app. Check tomcats log for warnings when you undeploy app. Also 4G for PermSize is TOO MUCH.